# Adding specific parameters to through for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

Being a beginner in Javascript and after failing with all the available solutions on this site, I am posting this question. I have a variable as given below:

```
var p = 
{
    "name": "Country",
    "entries": [{
        "value": "India",
        "synonyms": []
    },
    {
        "value": "USA",
        "synonyms": []
    }
   ]
};
```

If I have an array of hundred countries, how can I loop through entries of variable p and add hundred countries to it?

Comment: Post a sample of the content of your array of countries.

Comment: Why do you want to loop? `p.entries.push(...moreCountries)` would append all elements of `moreCountries` to `p.entries`. `p` only has two properties, so looping doesn't seem to me necessary? Either way, if you want help you should provide a complete example. That includes examples of the inputs and an example of the desired output. Also this is not JSON, it's an object literal.

Comment: When I say more specifically you can use the code as `p.entries.push({"value" : i,"synonyms":array_variable});`

Answer (score 1):

In ES6 you can use [spread argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for this task:

```
//...
var arrayOfCountries = [
  {
     "value": "Germany",
     "synonyms": []
  },
  {
    "value": "Russia",
    "synonyms": []
  }
]; 

p.entries.push(...arrayOfCountries);
```

Or if you are using ES5 or older try [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat?v=a) method:

```
// ...
p.entries = p.entries.concat(arrayOfCountries);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through p.entries

e.g.

```
for ( var i = 0 ; i < p.entries.length ; i++){
var value = p.entries[i].value;
var synonyms = p.entries[i].synonyms;
```

}

Comment: OP is asking to add an array of countries to the existing `p` object.

Comment: Yes, I am asking how to add things into the array